# Javamail: How to check emails being read using img insertation?

Tags: email, jakarta-mail

I have read alot of articles stating that in order to check if your recipient has read your mail, there are a few ways. One of which is to use read receipts, which i have done, but due to the constraints of needing to enable the auto read receipt in the clients, i am looking for alternatives. The one i found is to send 1 pixel image and check it back on my server.

Could someone explain how this can be done in java? What will i require to carry this out?

Apart from image insertions is there any other alternative worth exploring?

Answer (score 1):

You embed an image reference in the html content of your message.  The image reference includes a unique number that you generate just for this message.  You keep track of that unique number in a table on the server.  You write a servlet (or similar) application that responds to the image request but also looks up the unique number in the table to know that the email was read.

Does that help?